# Any way to remap ls from Get-ChildItem to another command in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, powershell-7.0

Trying to replace the default PowerShell `Get-ChildItem` command (mapped to `ls` by default in PowerShell 7) with [eza](https://github.com/eza-community/eza), however I cannot seem to find anything on how to do so

- Using `New-Alias` results in *alias is not allowed*

```
Line |
  15 |  New-Alias -Name ls -Value eza.exe # Eza map to ls
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The alias is not allowed, because an alias with the name 'ls' already exists.
```

- Using the following function does not work and it just calls `Get-ChildItem` again (although if i, for example, switch `ls` to `la` it does work so i don't think the function itself is incorrect)

```
function ls {
    [string]$Path # path for ls
    eza.exe -lab --group-directories-first --git --icons $Path
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`-Force`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-alias?view=powershell-7.3#-force) to override an existing alias:

```bash
New-Alias -Name ls -Value eza.exe -Force
```

Or even simpler, use [`Set-Alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-7.3) or assign a value using the [`alias:` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.3#scope-modifiers):

```bash
Set-Alias ls -Value eza.exe
# or
$alias:ls = 'eza.exe'
```

As for defining a function with the same name, note that aliases in PowerShell are at the top of the [Command Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence?view=powershell-7.3#command-precedence), meaning, a function with the same name will not override them.

You can however, name your function differently and decorate it with the [`Alias` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/alias-attribute-declaration?view=powershell-7.3), then you're good (note, you're missing a [`param` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.3) too):

```bash
function My-Func {
    [alias('ls')]
    param(
        [string]$Path # path for ls
    )

    eza.exe -lab --group-directories-first --git --icons $Path
}
```